# Non-unicode filenames on webserver

Tags: asp.net, apache, iis, drupal-6, non-unicode

Recently I've decided to install an intranet web application (Open Atrium) in our company, but almost immideately I found myself in trouble. 
We have huge directory - subdirectory file system with mixed Greek (Non Unicode) and English filenames. It seems that neither Apache nor IIS can handle reading or writing these files through browser.

What I am trying to achieve is to retain Filenames intact during reading and especially when uploading them.

Note: Transliteration process is not an option due to renaming files will loose their meaning, thus the existened ammount of files are huge and just cannot be renamed

So, my question are : am I missing something? are there any other servers (e.g JSP) which handle this problem gracefully?

Thank you in advance

My configuration is Xampp on Windows, Drupal 6, Open Atrium

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you looking for, but I can give you some tips. The way you handle the files can be setup on web.config under the globalization. One of this parametres maybe need to be change, if its the file name that you can not read, then the `fileEncoding` must be correctlty set to your file names.

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <globalization
      fileEncoding="utf-8"
      requestEncoding="utf-8"
      responseEncoding="utf-8"
      culture="en-US"
      uiCulture="de-DE"
    />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Some MSDN links about globalization.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/39d1w2xf.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.systemwebsectiongroup.globalization.aspx