# Spanish Characters not displaying correctly on Server ASP.NET production server but fine on my dev box

Tags: asp.net, unicode

Spanish Characters not displaying correctly on Server ASP.NET production server but fine on my dev box.  I have my page set with:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

The page renders properly on my development PC but on production server it is throwing up garbage characters.  Any ideas why this is happening?

**My Dev Box displays characters properly**

[image: My Dev box]

**But Production Server shows garbage characters**

[image: Production Server]

Answer (score 1):

This issue have to do with the encoding of your aspx files and the way the asp.net reads them.

Make sure that you have set on `web.config` the `utf-8` on `globalization`

```
<globalization requestEncoding="utf-8" responseEncoding="utf-8" fileEncoding="utf-8"/>
```

and that your files are also saved as Unicode `utf-8`

To save with different encoding open the save as, click on the button `save` to open the `Save with encoding`;

If you do not want the utf-8, change the `globalization` to your country code / as you have saved on your file.

There is also the possibility to have upload them as text using ftp, and maybe you break that encoding if you all ready have utf-8, so check also the ftp to upload them as binary.

you can also check
[Non-unicode filenames on webserver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8862408/non-unicode-filenames-on-webserver/8866181#8866181)